# How to get property types of a given Entity type in Xodus?

Tags: java, xodus

Is there a way for Xodus API to check the type of property? 
Xodus have a method `txn.getEntityTypes();` but I have not found a way to get the property types of a given Entity Type, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get property types of a given entity type. In case if all entities of the given entity type have the same set of properties, one can take an entity of given entity type and use method “entity.getPropertyNames()”.

Comment: We have a API that let's client write data with flexible types, but I want to prevent a property to be saved with different type, for example if a property is already set to be String then it should not allow to save other types, like a Number or Object, just String will be allowed, for reasons that you have said before if two property are different then it would break find

Comment: @xybrek there is no possibility to check types that way out-of-the-box.

Comment: Thanks, we have solved this with the approach in this answer, getting the properties and iterating over it checking the value types